# EC2 instance cannot ping outside after I associate EIP with secondary IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with Amazon Linux AMI with NAT.
For eth0, if I associate EIP with primary IP 10.0.0.12, I can ping outside.
If I associate EIP with seconary IP 10.0.0.200, I cannot ping outside.

The routing table for subnet has two entries (default one and entry to internet gateway).

Below is IP and routing info.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-12 ~]$ ip addr list eth0

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000

link/ether 02:2a:9b:b6:5a:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 10.0.0.12/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet 10.0.0.200/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global secondary eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 fe80::2a:9bff:feb6:5a7a/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-12 ~]$ ip route

default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 

default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth1  metric 10001 

default via 10.0.4.1 dev eth2  metric 10002 

10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.12 

10.0.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.12 

10.0.4.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.4.12 

169.254.169.254 dev eth0
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, can other EC2 instances communicate with that server via its secondary private IP address?

Comment: Symptom is same for other EC2 instance.

Comment: Therefore, it has nothing to do with the Elastic IP address. It is related to how the instance is configured to accept the incoming private IP address.

Comment: I guess the root cause is source ip of traffic is primary ip and AWS routing mechanism cannot find binding info. If so, it is not convient for customer.